# Left align drop down menu under parent

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, parent-child

I've spent days trying to left-align my drop down menus under their parents. The only CSS & HTML I know is what I've learned through the process in the past few days, so treat me like a child in your responses, lol.  You'll see that I've only survived this so far by making notes on what everything means...

Here's my Blog so you can see what it's doing crittndesign.blogspot.com  I started out with just the "Featured Products" tab & drop down when I initially created the menu.  In order to align the drop down under the parent, I put an actual value on how far from the left I wanted it (68px seemed to work).  It did what I wanted for the time being, but then I decided to add the "Inspiration for..." tab and now you see I need to actually fix my problem and have the proper coding for the menus to left align under their own parent tabs.

My code is probably a mess since I've tried so many different things now, but I need someone to tell me specifically what to change to make it right!  I read a lot about needing the position to be either "relative" or "inline-block" but I apparently don't know where to stick it because it always breaks the drop down as soon as I remove the fixed position (Left: 68px).  Let me know if you need any other info in order to help me figure it out!

Thanks in advance!!

CSS

```
    .navigation ul ul { 
        display: none;
    }
    .navigation ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    .navigation li ul {    
        position: absolute;  /*makes the list actually drop down*/
        z-index:100;    /*makes it stay visible when moving mouse down to it*/
        left: -999em;    /*em=scaleable*/
        width: 165px;    /*width of drop down box*/
        margin: 19px 0 0 0; 
        padding: 0; 
    }
    .navigation li:hover ul {   
        left: 68px;    /* position of drop down menu aligned under parent */
    }
    .navigation li li a {    /*how the drop down menu itself looks*/
        display: block; 
        background: #663300; 
        width: 140px;     /*width of background color on drop down*/
        color: #FF9900; 
        font:normal 12px Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        padding: 9px 13px 12px 12px; 
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-align:center;
        border-bottom: 2px dotted #060505; /*dotted line under each menu item in drop down*/
    }
    .navigation li li a:hover { /*how the drop down menu looks when hovered over*/
        background: #060505; 
        color: #FFFFFF;  
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 9px 13px 12px 12px; /*for the list names when hovered over them*/
        text-decoration: bold; 
        border-bottom: 1px #060505; 
        text-align:center;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
    } 
    li:hover > a { /*Color all hovered links, and keep menu item colored when hovering sub-menu*/ 
        background-color: #663300; 
    } 
    .navigation li ul ul { 
        /*margin: -35px 0 0 145px;*/
    } 
    .navigation li:hover ul ul { 
        left: -9999em; 
    } 
    .navigation li ul li:hover ul { 
       left: auto;  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your markup, but try this...

```
.navigation ul{
 padding:0;
}
```

All the ul's have default padding and margin, so for the dropped ul's in the parent ul, they should have 0 padding to align to left.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all the css you got ? 
Any parent Css ? have you assigned positioning to the 
         
(body) attribute ? 
All the positionings you specify are relative to what position the  is.